# UITableView display multi image

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I display multi-image in UITableView?

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself? This a Q&A site, not a body shop. Don't ask people to write it for you; ask for help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom UITableViewCell by subclassing. There is an extensive tutorial about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) in the Apple Developer Center. There are also many tutorials about this in web, here is [one](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/) I found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UITableViewCell and add something like an NSArray of UIImage ivar to display in each cell (or 4 UIImage ivars if this number is fixed).